# Can not read "property" of undefined reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple problem that I don't know why it happens. I need to render something from localStorage, but this value is set when the user searches for something..so I can render in the next search, the last "something" searched.

```
const Home = () => {
 
    const { contextState } = useContext(ContentContext)

    const [valInStorage, setValInStorage ] = useState({})

    useEffect(()=>{    

        const storageValue = localStorage.getItem('values')

        if(storageValue !== null && storageValue !== undefined){
            setValInStorage(JSON.parse(storageValue))
        }
       
    },[])
    
     console.log(valInStorage)

     let valInfo = Object.values(contexState).filter(item => typeof item === "object")

     return (
         <div className={`siteContent`}>

            <SearchBar />

            <Fragment> 
                
                 <h2>Result</h2>
                    
                   {
                      valInfo.map( item => ( item !== null ? 
                          <Card key={item.id} data={item}/> : 
                          <h3 key={1}>No item to show</h3>) 
                         )
                   }
                        
                  <h2>Last value searched</h2>
                  {/*the error occurs when the card component receives an undefined value. */}
                  {contextState !== undefined ? (<Card data= 
                  {valInStorage}/>):(<p>Nothing here</p>)}
               
      </Fragment>
```

The strange thing for me is that I'm telling you, if the value is undefined that it will render something else...I also tried :

```
{contextState !== undefined && (<Card data={valInStorage}/>)}
```

keeps throwing up the error. I understand why the error occurs. It happens because I'm passing an undefined value to the Card component. What I don't understand is why the conditionals don't work.

I just thought it would prevent the component from receiving an undefined or null value if I applied a simple control structure as usual.

Comment: Try adding another condition to check if "valInStorage" is undefined.

Comment: Try to add another dependency valInStorage or contextState to UseEffect , add another check for both I mentiod `{ valInStorage && <mycompnent>}`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `contexState` in Object.values instead of `contextState` which is probably responsible for error.

As for your state, it also probably has incorrect data which is causing issue, you will need to `console.log(valInStorage)` and see its value to identify the issue here.

Finally, make sure your `useEffect` runs when your store is updated, you will need to pass a prop when your localStorage is updated and set that prop as a dependancy for useEffect. Currently, your useEffect will only work once when the component mounts.